# How to generate a list of elements from an expresion that has (==)

Tags: list-manipulation

Hello and thanks for your time in advance.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to make a list of elements from the following expression:

```
(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 == r^2
```

What I'm trying to do is generate a list with a definite set of values for `h` and `k` with a fixed value of `r`, to get something like this:

```
{(-1 + x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2 == 1, (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 == 1, (-3 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2 == 1}
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```
(-h + x)^2 + (-k + y)^2 == r^2 /. {h :> Range[1, 3], k :> Range[1, 3],r -> 1}
```

And from that I'm getting this:

```
   {(-1 + x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2, (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2, (-3 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2} == 1
```

I'm looking for any pointers on what I'm doing wrong because I can't figure it out.

Again thanks for any pointers, help or comments that could help me to figure out what to do.

Comment: How about using Table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an example...

```
Flatten[Table[(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 == r^2, {h, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]]
```

results in...

{(-1 + x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2 == r^2, (-1 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 == 
  r^2, (-1 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2 == r^2, (-2 + x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2 == 
  r^2, (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 == r^2, (-2 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2 == 
  r^2, (-3 + x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2 == r^2, (-3 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 == 
  r^2, (-3 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2 == r^2}

Isn´t that what you are looking for ?

Taking your comments into account, I would rewrite that as...

```
Table[(x - h)^2 + (y - h)^2 == r^2, {h, 1, 3}]
```

And you can do away with Flatten as well.

Comment: Hello FACamargo, something like that but how you stop the permutations between h and k. Because like i was trying to explain im looking to get this {(-1 + x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2 == 1, (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 == 1, (-3 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2 == 1}, thats why i use RuleDelayed (:>) in the example i show in my initial post. But really thanks for your ideas.

Comment: What about making h = k, and having just one iterator? It would produce exactly what you asked for...

Comment: Awesome thats it thanks man, i feel dumb now lol. Thanks alot :D

Comment: Don't worry, I know the feeling... We are both neophytes here :)